# Deleting 'garbage' nodes after polygon dissolve

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve

I work with QGIS 2.10.1 on Windows 7 (x64). I have dissolved polygons from an attribute value and the polygons geometries being not perfectly joined together, I get some 'garbage' nodes I need to delete. I have tried to edit the layer and using nodes tool, selecting and deleting the nodes, but it seems impossible to do (nodes are not deleted at all!). Any idea on how to process this kind of clean-up?

**EDIT :** you can [download the shapefile here](http://mails-ng.optimails.com/~t-williamson@eauxdevienne.fr/protected/mydocuments/forums/pwd/quAt1EJG/center.zip) for testing.

[image][image]

Comment: Those are called sliver polygons, this might help you find more information.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. But my problem remains: I can't select the sliver polygons in order to merge them with the bigger ones (using new tool **Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Eliminate sliver polygons**).

Comment: Try to use the [Node Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer) and remove the vertices of the sliver polygons.

Comment: I wrote in my post that this tool did not work...

Comment: Perhaps you could upload and share your shapefile so that others could test it?

Comment: Just edited my post and enabled file download for testing.

Comment: This can be indicative of geometry errors in the source data. I would suggest running validate geometry before dissolving (or on the result). Have you seen these related questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94832/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48511/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148350/? For what little it's worth, while Arc detected geometry errors in the file you posted, I had no problem deleting some of the errant nodes. However, you should be aware there are *multiple* nodes stacked on top of each other - you may only be deleting the topmost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested your shapefile and used GRASS algorithm **v.clean** from the *Processing Toolbox*. I applied `snap` as the cleaning tool and used a threshold of `5` which seemed to have cleaned up your shapefile a fair bit.

This is your original shapefile loaded:

[image: Original shapefile]

This is it *cleaned* using GRASS (notice the little yellow polygon that was dissolved originally but is now separate):

[image: Cleaned shapefile]

Just to show the difference in nodes, here was the original:

[image: Original nodes]

And here it is after being cleaned:

[image: Cleaned nodes]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks @Joseph! This worked perfectly... I'm not used to GRASS functions, I should deep in those in the coming times.

Comment: @wiltomap - Awesome buddy, glad it worked for you too and it wasn't just a fluke for me! Yup, GRASS has some pretty powerful tools so check them out :)